# QListView icon mode not relayout when resize

Tags: qt, qlistview

I have a QListView with IconMode view, LeftToRight flow, and wrapping is true.
But I have a problem when I resize the widget that the item is not relayout.
Is there any way to make it relayout? Many thanks for any help.

Start listview :
[image: List view at start]

List view after resize :
[image: after resize]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the resize mode
`setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust)`

The default is "Fixed" not "Adjust"

Look here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#resizeMode-prop

And: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#ResizeMode-enum

And:https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#isWrapping-prop

Comment: thanks for your help, I have another problem. I have 1000 data in my model, when it resize -> it really heavy. Is there anything to do to optimize it?